# Old operating system (offline computer) need to come online for a few minutes

Tags: attack-prevention, macos, updates

OSX El Capitan

I have an offline computer running an old OSX operating system.
I would like to connect that computer to the web for a brief few minutes in order to install HomeBrew and install a newer version of rsync.  I will use the command line.

What can I do to reduce security risks while connecting?

Maybe block some traffic through my router?  There wont be other computers/ devices on my network needing to connect at the same time.
I can probably connect through a mobile phone (Android 9.0 or iOS 14) if that helps at all.

Answer (score 3):

If you are connecting through a router and not browsing the Internet, your risks are minimal. The risks would be if the computer was directly exposed to the Internet or you started browsing, opening emails, etc.

Your Mac will probably send a lot of traffic out to get updates, etc. But that's not a risk.

If you have other programs running that might "phone home", like browsers, apps, etc. I'd make sure those weren't running, just in case you end up getting a malicious update (usually through apps made through small or independent developers).